# PHP mail function is not working?

Tags: php, forms, email

```
$to = 'abc@xyz.com';
$subject = 'Feedback';
$finalmessage = "";
$from = 'def@ghi.com';

$finalmessage = $name . $address . $phnum . $email . $feedback;
$finalmessage = wordwrap($finalmessage, 70);

$mail=mail($to,$subject,$finalmessage,"From: $from\n");

if($mail){
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
}else{
  echo "Mail sending failed."; 
}
```

Thats the code. At the end it displays "Thank you for using our mail form", but i am not receiving any mail. Any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: are you using it at local?

Comment: Probably a server configuration issue. Did you see all the links on the right ---> ? One of these surely has your answer. You are not the first person with this problem.

Comment: You should use it in a hosting (May be freehosting) such as http://www.000webhost.com to make it work. You shall refer this for code ,http://sysaxiom.com/php/email_system.php

Comment: I am trying to run it via apache server on xampp.

Comment: did you replace $to to your email ?

Comment: Do you have an smtp server installed?

Comment: Well i actually did upload it to my school server but still not working and yeah i checked almost all of those links on the right.

Comment: i dont have a smtp server installed but cant i just enable the mercury smtp server from xampp?

Comment: @rancour86,did you check in span also

Answer (score 1):

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

```
$to="email";
 // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['Email_Address']; // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['Full_Name'];
$tel_num=$_POST['Telephone_Number'];
$msg=$_POST['Your_Message'];
$subject = "Full Name : ".$first_name;

$headers = "From: ".$first_name." <".$from.">\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

$message="Full Name : ".$first_name."<br><br>Telephone Number : ".$tel_num."<br><br>Message : ".$msg;

$bericht = nl2br($message);

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure SMTP settings of your local server in `php.ini` file as follows:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost // your smtp server
smtp_port = 25
```

Or you should give try to [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: On which email address you are sending email. As there can be possibility that from your school server outgoing email are blocked

Comment: i was sending it to hotmail

Comment: say if it is blocked on the school server, but shouldn't that be working on the localhost?

Comment: as far as i can see there seems to be nothing wrong with the code itself?

Comment: @rancour86,check in span also

Comment: Try to send email to internal email address which is related to your schools sever.

Comment: it failed when i tried to send it to an internal address

Comment: Are you sure that you aer connected to internet or your SMTP port is not blocked by firewall.

Comment: i am connected to the internet but not sure if the smtp port is blocked by firewall

Comment: Try http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/888/Checking+your+outgoing+mail+server+%28Is+Port+25+blocked%3F%29

Answer (score 0):

Use php mailer() function

You can use PHPmailer :
http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/

Now
use following code -

```
       <?php
      require("class.phpmailer.php"); // give proper path of folder if needed
      $mail = new PHPMailer();

      session_start(); 
      ob_start();   
      php?>

      <your mail body goes here>



      <?php
      $body=ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean ();
      $to = 'abc@xyz.com';
      $subject = 'Feedback';
      $finalmessage = "";
      $from = 'def@ghi.com';

      $finalmessage = $name . $address . $phnum . $email . $feedback;
      $finalmessage = wordwrap($finalmessage, 70);
      $mail->Host = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
      $mail->IsHTML(true); 
      $mail=mail($to,$subject,$finalmessage,"From: $from\n");

      if($mail){
        echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
      }else{
        echo "Mail sending failed."; 
       }
```

Comment: i know but still cant figure out whats wrong with this code ?

Comment: your code is ok...but server is not supporting for mail sending...so i think u have to use phpmailer

Answer (score 0):

Try using fake sendmail to send emails in a windows enviroment.

http://jesin.tk/using-sendmail-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your mail SMTP in php.ini
It's quite simple, what is your ISP? For example, in comcast, just search in Google "comcast smtp address and port"

Take note of the SMTP address and Port, then go to your php.ini
Search for this configuration:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost // your smtp server
smtp_port = 25
```

Change the address with the SMTP and smtp_port. Then you should be able to send emails in your localhost